# What ending marks should be used to extend a range to the end of the paragraph?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I am coding a word add-in and am not clear how to use the getNextTextRange(endingMarks, trimSpacing) method of the Range class.

Specifically I want to select a new Range starting from the currently selected range and going to the end of the paragraph.

The API for for the method states

> **endingMarks** *string[]*
>   Required. The punctuation marks and/or other 
>   ending marks as an array of strings

That's clear enough if you want to select up to the next comma, period or even space. But what ending marks should you use for a paragraph, a line break, or the end of the document?

I have tried using '\n', '^p' and '¶' but none of these seem to work.

```
          var nr = selection.getNextTextRange(['¶'],true);
           nr.load("isEmpty,text");
           await context.sync();
           console.log('nr='+nr.text);
         } catch(e) {
          console.log("error, soz");
          console.log(e);
         }
```

Given a document consisting of one paragraph of text with a blank paragraph after it, and the first word of the paragraph highlighted, this add-in throws a **RichApi.Error**

> We couldn't find the item you requested.

I would expect it to instead print out the remainder of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your scenario, you can work with the [ParagraphCollection.getFirst()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word_release/word.paragraphcollection?view=office-js#getfirst--) method. Please install the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862?tab=Overview) tool. Open the sample called "Get paragraph from insertion point" for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand on rick-kirkham's answer in case it helps anyone else in my situation. This is basically the same answer as given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160690/4114053

Ok, here is my sample word document:

> The rain in Spain falls. Mainly on the plain.
>
> Alice stepped through the looking glass. What did she see?
>
> And there endeth the lesson. Amen.

The user selects "stepped" in the second paragraph and I want to know what the text for the rest of the paragraph, from that word, says. I also want to know what the text up to that point says.

```
var doc = context.document;
var selection = doc.getSelection(); 
selection.load("isEmpty,text");
await context.sync();
console.log(selection.text); //prints stepped

var startRange = selection.getRange("start"); 
var endRange = selection.paragraphs.getLast().getRange("start");
var deltaRange = startRange.expandTo(endRange);
context.load(deltaRange);
await context.sync();
console.log(deltaRange.text); //prints "Alice"

startRange = selection.getRange("end"); 
endRange = selection.paragraphs.getLast().getRange("end");
deltaRange = startRange.expandTo(endRange);
context.load(deltaRange);

await context.sync();
console.log(deltaRange.text); // prints "through the looking glass. What did she see?"
```

My mistake was to get too caught up in trying to work out what "ending marks" might mean and how to use them to achieve this. (Although I still would like that spelled out in the API specification.)